# foreach inside of another foreach in Yii2

Tags: php, foreach, yii2

I try the next:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $json[] = [
            'img_url' => "mysite.com/images/content/" . $post->imgUrl,
        ];
}
```

Now I need to add a new parameter, but there are many objects and I need to use foreach inside of foreach:

```
'gallery' => foreach ($post->gallery->galleryMedia as $mediaItem) { $mediaItem->imgUrl }
```

but it prints

```
syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)
```

How can I take all elements of gallery inside of foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all `$post->gallery->galleryMedia` items inside a variable then use it in your `$json` variable.

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $galleries = array();
    foreach ($post->gallery->galleryMedia as $mediaItem) { 
        $galleries[] = $mediaItem->imgUrl 
    }
    $json[] = [
        'img_url' => "mysite.com/images/content/" . $post->imgUrl,
        'gallery' => $galleries
    ];
}
```